# UDP Packet including header

Tags: c#, udp

I have made simple UDP Client / Server application. The client send server a text message.
All works fine. My question is: when I open Wireshark, i see that total length of the packet 
is bigger then I see it in code and I assume that this is because of the header that being append to the data. Is there any way to get the full packet (header + payload) on server side?
I seen multiple threads on winpcap but it's not what I'm looking for. I need UDP listener that will receive data with header as byte array.

Comment: Why do you need to access the UDP header? That is information required by the UDP/TCP stack and is totally transparent to the application. You haver to include all the data you want to send inside the payload of your udp packets.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with native .Net. Reading / writing raw frames is the job of the network stack, not the application. Are you sure you really need to do this?

If you really must, you will have to use a winpcap wrapper such as [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).